# PhoneGap on Windows Server

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm new to PhoneGap.

I know it's all about html and javascript.

Can I host it on a Windows Shared server?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Phonegap(html js and so on) normally get compiled(lack of better word) into apk. You can of course have services on Windows Servers. And if you want you can store html css and js on the Window server of course online apps will most probably not be the best candidate for this.

Comment: Thank you I used phonegap build to build the app in apk and ipa. Then I used inappbrowser plugin to display my asp.net pages hosted on my windows server. That worked for me.